# MacBook, Use external 4k screen in HiDPI mode in non-native resolution

Tags: macos, display, resolution, macbook, macbook-pro

I am about to buy a 4k screen that has 3840x2160 resolution. However, since I have the late 2013 13" RMBP, my MacBook can only drive the monitor with 30 Hz when I use the native resolution. Therefore I would like to set it to 2560x1440 until I buy a new MacBook.

Now comes the catch: even this smaller resolution results in too small text, hence I would like to use 1920x1080 or 1680x1050 virtual resolution.

At the store I connected my MBP to a test monitor and played a bit with SwitchResX. I could achieve either native resolution (3840x2160) with 1920x1080 virtual resolution in HiDPI mode or use 2560x1440 as display and virtual resolution when everything was too small.

Summing up what I need:

- maximum resolution supported by the monitor: 3840x2160
- actual output resolution: 2560x1440
- virtual resolution: 1920x1080

Is it possible to achieve the above with any system-provided or third-party software? Thank you for the answers.

My device:

- 13" Retina Macbook Pro (late 2013)
- 2.4 Ghz, 16GB RAM
- OS X Yosemite